# Multiclient Google plus Oauth using Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, oauth, google-plus

We have a Phonegap app (Android and iOS) and web app with web API that need to use Google plus authorization. We can't figure out how to implement that. So far we only accomplished to obtain access token from mobile app and send it to server, but that's not how it's supposed to be done for several reasons.

What we are trying to accomplish is to obtain authorization code from mobile app, send it to web component and get access token and refresh token there, which is the right way, and that's how it's done using native iOS and Android SDK, but for some reason it either can't be done using Phonegap, or we just can't figure it out. For web app it woks normally. If someone has experience with this that would be very useful.

The important thing is that user can log in from different devices and that API can recognise him and use refresh token to authorize.

It would also be nice if we could use the same app id for all clients.

Comment: Use inAppBrowser. There are also examples here in so for making an oauth call from cordova. Look into it.

Comment: I am using InAppBrowser, it's not a problem to authorize from the app but the problem is that web service makes the api calls and needs to authorize too, and the web service itself should obtain the access token and refresh token.

Comment: Then set the redirect to be the server url that receives the token.

Comment: I don't think it would make any difference, but i can try. The problem is when I obtain the authorization code from the client and send it to the server, the server then can't use it to get the access token, but gets the "unauthorized client" error. I suppose that the same thing would happan if i set the redirect url to the server, 'cause basically it would send the same autorization code to the server

Comment: Maybe you didnt configure correctly the console key (redirect url etc).